# Create React App - video loaded with webpack is not included in URLs to precache

Tags: webpack, service-worker, create-react-app, sw-precache

I'm using `sw-precache`via `create-react-app` to enable my app for use offline. I have a video that is loaded via `webpack`, but I noticed that it is not included in the generated `serviceWorker`'s `precacheConfig` array.

How can I force `webpack` / `sw-precache` to include the (hashed) video in the list of URLs to prefetch?

Comment: So you would like to cache the video in order to be playable in offline mode?

Comment: @MatthewBarbara, Yes, but I can already do that if I play the complete video before going offline, or by `fetch`ing the video and saving the `blob` to `IndexedDB` and then doing something like `video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)`.  I am specifically looking for a way to have the video added to the service worker's precache list to be able to know that everything, including the video, is cached once the service worker's `installed` event fires. Currently the `installed` event fires before the video is cached.

Comment: I'm not sure why the video isn't already included using `create-react-app`'s default set up.

Comment: I haven't seen your code but here is a working example of a working sw using video for offline use. https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/prefetch-video/

Comment: Yes, I've seen this too.  I'm wondering how that can be integrated with `create-react-app`'s setup (either ejected or not).